# ajax or jquery post json request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to make post json call but it is showing call type "text/html" in develepors tools

here is my ajax and jquery call both of them posting same call

```
var dataString='query='+search_value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/reports/search', 
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataString,
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success"+data);
            }
        });

jquery
        $.post( "/reports/search", { query: search_value},function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          },"json");
```

here is the screenshot of the request

what's wrong with my request
[image]

Comment: That is because the response (the 404) is returned as text/html. Correct the URL first, then examine. Besides, the dataType is what you're expecting to receive, it doesn't control what is actually sent.

Comment: `"what's wrong with my request"` - You're requesting a resource that the server can't find: `/reports/search`.  Either the URL is wrong or there's something wrong on the server.  We can't know with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var dataString='query='+search_value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourbase url'+'/reports/search', 
        type: 'post',
```

You have to define your base URL or proper URL to make Ajax call.